# Wordpress - remove all classes added by WP on pictures

Tags: wordpress, class, format

When I add pictures in an article on wordpress, wordpress automatically add classes to the pictures.
eg :

I simply want to desactivate those added classes, of which I do not see the point and actually annoys me when I want to center a group of pictures.

How can I do so?

I've read about the following filter :
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );

But given that the pictures classes seems dynamical (picture id?), how can I do so? And... where should I do that fork?
Any other method to clean that code?

Thanks !

Comment: Just add it to function.php

Answer (score 0):

Solved as previously mentionned in the answers, thanks !

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32065090)

Comment: In this case, there isn't an answer for you to accept - there is only a comment. So, one option is for you to invite the commenter to convert their comment into an answer (which you could then accept, if you chose to - noting that accepting and voting are always completely optional steps). But what you have provided here is not, in itself, an answer to the question. You could also just edit this answer yourself, to make it clear what the solution is.

Comment: @Youssef El Behi but I didnt have the acceptance option...

Comment: @andrewJames : Exactly, I didnt have the option. I am still newish to stacko, so still learning. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @YoussefElBehi - what answer are you referring to?

Comment: @jeremy you can update your answer and explain how you solved the problem. This will be helpful for other users facing the same issue.

Comment: @YoussefElBehi
 


It's from 3 years ago, but checking my functions.php it seems it was added in it, just like dan webb suggested in his answer.

So, the answer that seem to have worked is :adding the following code in the functions.php 
 
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );